# Creating Alert box on back pressed

Tags: android

I want to prompt a message when back is pressed and delete few db if yes is pressed and if no is pressed it just goes back but when im using the following code it pops up and then just disappears and and im redirected to the previous activity.

the code im using

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener1 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:


                    firebaseDatabase3.removeValue();
                    firebaseDatabase4.removeValue();
                    startActivity(new Intent(BarcodeReaderActivity2.this,Edit.class));
                    finish();


                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                    startActivity(new Intent(BarcodeReaderActivity2.this,MainActivity.class));

                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeReaderActivity2.this);
    builder.setMessage("Press Yes to Delete current order and press No to go back").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener1)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener1).show();


    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

from the bottom of the code,

If you want to go back you don't need to add `Intent` in `case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:` just add the `super.onBackPressed();`

Hope this will help!